How to force Intel Graphics Driver version 10.18.15.4279 not to be updated?
I have a 10-year old Lenovo Y50-70 that still works great (running Windows 10) and with its 16GB RAM still runs fast enough for what I do.
However, Microsoft's automated updates also updates my Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 driver to version 20.19.15.4624 which breaks its ability to properly identify additional displays connected through the the HDMI port.
When I reinstall the latest Intel Graphics Driver downloadable from Lenovo (version 10.18.15.4279), all is well.
But at night, Windows somehow "corrects" itself to version 20.19.15.4624 and ruins my dual display setup.
How can I force Windows to retain this particular 10.18.15.4279 version of the  Intel Graphics Driver?

UPDATE: The suggested registry tweak below didn't work in my Windows 10 Home, so I am trying now the suggested "Show or hide updates" utility:

UPDATE II: The suggested "Show or hide updates" ( wushowhide.diagcab) utility works for me.

You can enable the Do not include drivers with Windows Update group policy to prevent the behavior you describe. if you don't have Windows 10 Professional you can create the ExcludeWUDriversInQualityUpdate key to prevent these optional driver updates from being installed.

You can also download and run wushowhide.diagcab to hide the update for the device.


How can I force Windows to retain this particular 10.18.15.4279 version of the Intel Graphics Driver?

You can enable the Do not include drivers with Windows Update group policy if you have Windows 10 Professional.  If you have Windows 10 Home you can manually create the key ExcludeWUDriversInQualityUpdate within HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate and set it to 1.
You can also run wushowhide.diagcab to hide the update in question.

I implemented yesterday the suggested registry tweak but Windows Update ignored it: The 20.19.15.4624 returned instead of the 10.18.15.4279 one... I am going to try now the wushowhide.diagcab one.

I can confirm that the wushowhide.diagcab tool solved the issue. Thank you
